# When uploading a file to the angular 6 input file, is there a way to get the real path of the file?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, filepath

```
<input hidden type="file" #file id="upload" (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" multiple>

uploadFile(event) {
this.message = '';
this.progressInfos = [];

for (let index = 0; index < event.length; index++) {
  const element = event[index];
  this.files.push(element);
  this.largeFiles.push(element);
}

this.selectedFiles = this.largeFiles;
console.log(this.selectedFiles);
for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
  this.uploadAsync(i, this.selectedFiles[i]);
 }
}
```

I want to know the real path of the file, not the fake path. Is there any way to know the real path when uploading a file?
I keep getting fake routes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: @spots This is TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: TypeScript just extends JavaScript by adding types. It gets turned into JavaScript when it's compiled. The language has nothing to do with knowing the full path because it's the browsers responsibility, and the browser won't tell you because it would be a security flaw.